# Angularjs - deregistering watchers

Tags: angularjs, memory-leaks

Does it pay to deregister angularjs watchers during scope destroy 
 process(registered by using scope.watch), in order to prevent memory leaks? 
I hear people advising to deregister all manual watchers in on("$destroy") event.

For instance, when we navigate to a different page in angular routing, all watchers should be automatically freed by angular and we don't have to worry about freeing them. (and we don't have to handle this by ourselves?)

Does it ever happen, that the registered watcher is not being released after angular destroys given scope so that a memory leak appears?

One problem I am seeing that manual handling deregistration of watchers clutters the code.

Answer (score 1):

Having too many $watch can create performance issues for webpages, especially on mobile devices. This post will explain how to remove extraneous $watch and accelerate your application!

Any $watch can be disabled when it is no longer needed. Thus, we have the freedom to choose when to remove a $watch from the $watch list.

Let’s see an example:

***File: app.js***

```
app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.updated = 0;

  $scope.stop = function() {
    textWatch();
  };

  var textWatch = $scope.$watch('text', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    if (newVal === oldVal) { return; }
    $scope.updated++;
  });
});
```

***File: index.html***

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="text" /> {{updated}} times updated.
  <button ng-click="stop()">Stop count</button>
</body>
```

The $watch function itself returns a function which will unbind the $watch when called. So, when the $watch is no longer needed, we simply call the function returned by $watch.

Comment: The problem is that angular documentation says we don't need to deregister watchers, Angular does it for us. 

I'm looking at the problem from the perspective of memory leaks. I understand that the performance benefits from freeing up watchers.


Are there any issues from the perspective of memory leaks when we, for instance, navigate to a different page in routing.